# SimpleDateFormat in Android giving current date as 02/32/2011

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

Today is February 1, 2011. I am trying to generate a date string for Android in the format "MM/DD/yyyy" using SimpleDateFormat. Here is my code:

```
Date d = new Date();
String date = (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/yyyy")).format(d);
```

It returns the following string:

```
02/32/2011
```

What is going on here? I can't see anything that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Use 'dd' in place of 'DD'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use "MM/dd/yyyy".  You're using the day in year instead of day in month.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: d'oh! That was indeed the problem. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`dd` is placeholder for day of month, not `DD`.

Comment: More specifically, "DD" is for day in year, where "dd" is for day in month.

Comment: Yeah, wanted to answer quickly, your reply is more detailed anyway ;)